# Maintaining customized versions of pyramid project (git branches, in-code variation, or other method?)

Tags: git, version-control, pyramid

### Introduction

I have a simple pyramid project for inventory management, and use git as my VCS. Switching away from git would not be hard, but switching away from pyramid would be. The scope of the project is quite small, meant for use by a single organization, with maybe 5-20 logins max at a time. The project is developed for A.

### Problem statement

B also wants an inventory management software, and I wish to re-use what I've already developed for A. There are certain fundamental differences (most importantly, the item models would differ as both A and B are interested in different attributes) as well as view differences (at the very least the logo on the page would differ, and B probably wants different pages based on their usage pattern, much more focused on keeping track of item loans where A is much more focused on ensuring timely delivery of items when purchase orders are sent to external suppliers).

### Example of fundamental differences

Both A and B would have models named Item and Group (Child-Parent relationship). However A would keep track of 5 attributes for Item (e.g. Brand, Part Number, Target Delivery Date, Actual Received Date, Description) while B would keep track of 4 attributes for Item (e.g. Identification Number, Description, Item type (consumable or re-usable), and Purchase Date).

### Alternatives considered

Having multiple branches off a single base (or a single submodule with common code) seems tough to keep synchronized/merged, mostly because I don't seem to have much 'common code' in the sense of fixed directories or files which would not change at all between versions.

Based on this talk - [always ship trunk](http://www.paulhammond.org/2010/06/trunk/alwaysshiptrunk.pdf) taken from the accepted answer to [Workflow for maintaining different versions of a webapp using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560166/workflow-for-maintaining-different-versions-of-a-webapp-using-git) the recommendation is instead to maintain a single branch (trunk/master, obviously feature development is a separate branch) but version in-code with if/else checks on flags. However it seems more suited to multiple versions of the same web-app rather than two (slightly differing) web-apps as in my case.

Which of the above (or other alternatives) would involve the least maintenance burden, assuming both A and B's requirements don't significantly branch away from each other (e.g. A requests that financial accounting be included, at which point I would actually just fork a separate project)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Pyramid, but rather than using a VCS-oriented approach (ie. branches), what you probably want is a modular approach. Something like this:

```
siteA/
    templates/
    config/
    assets/
    tests/
siteB/
    templates/
    config/
    assets/
    tests/
modules/
    inventory/
    financial/
    image_gallery/
```

The details of each site are kept separate from each other. They have their own templates, configuration, and assets (images, and whatnot) that describe how they behave and how they look.

Bits of functionality are developed as configurable modules. This is your inventory system, your financial system, an image gallery... whatever.

Then siteA and siteB can individually choose which modules they want to use, configure how they act, and how they look.

The main advantage is that the details of the sites are decoupled from each other, so you can cater to the whims of your individual customers without changing how the other behaves. Someone can work on siteA without worrying about breaking siteB. Common functionality is put into the modules which have a more formal, documented interface.

The main disadvantage is that if A and B have a lot in common it can get redundant. There's various ways to mitigate that: push more common functionality into the modules, create shared templates, symlink to common templates and assets, improve the default configuration of modules, or even branches.

Comment: Interesting, though there does seem to be a lot of redundancy built-in here (not very DRY).

Comment: @NgOon-Ee DRY wrestles with decoupling. Devil's in the details, and you didn't provide many, so this is just a sketch. You say A and B have "fundamental differences" so they have to be separate entities; using branches to separate them is too coarse. Instead, find the common functionality and move that into shared, configurable sub-components. While things that are likely to change, probably the parts having to do with the view (templates and assets and even controllers), should be separate, but a good template system will also be configurable and modular allowing some sharing and reuse.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to provide a general question rather than delving too much into my implementation specifics. The "fundamental differences" I referred to were primarily about the models, while both should at this point in time be using the same general model layouts, the specific models used will certainly differ. Will add an example into the question for clarity.

Comment: @NgOon-Ee The answer remains the same. Adding or removing attributes to a model should be easy, and modules can say what attributes they require and which are optional. What's more interesting is what you intend to do with them. They're both inventory systems, but one has an order fulfillment component, so you'd need an order fulfillment module, and the other needs to track who's been loaned what, like a library. These modules would require (or add themselves) extra attributes to your model. A and B would decide which modules they're using, and configure them to their tastes.

Comment: thanks, looks like I need to check that substantive part of your comment "adding or removing attributes to a model" as the SQLAlchemy backend I use is declarative currently.

Comment: @NgOon-Ee What you're looking for are "migrations" or "schema change management". I don't know SQLAlchemy in particular, but most ORMs will manage the schema for you these days. If it can't ***pick another ORM*** because you're going to want to change the schema for many reasons. You should also consider if it makes sense to be essentially writing your own application framework rather than using an existing one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135547/discussion-between-ng-oon-ee-and-schwern).